# Facebook Private Message in Titanium

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to send  Facebook Private in my Titanium Application.I have tried in following two ways but i didn't get any success.

**Method 1:**

```
var data = {
    link: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript",
    name: "Best online Javascript reference",
    message: "Use Mozilla's online Javascript reference",
    test: [ {foo:'Encoding test', bar:'Durp durp'}, 'test' ]
};
var friendFbId = "xxx"
var path = friendFbId+"/feed"

Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(path, 'POST', data, showRequestResult);
```

It is works fine but it is posted in my friend's timeline. But I need a private message(should be visible to my friend only).

**Method 2:**

```
var data1 = {
    link: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript",
    name: "Best online Javascript reference"
};

 Titanium.Facebook.dialog("send", data1, showRequestResult);
```

I am getting folowing error

> error_code=3&error_msg=This+method+is+not+supported+for+this+display+type

Any one help me to solve this issue. I am using Titanium 1.7.5 and ios. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook the send dialog is currently not supported on mobile devices:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't allow for private messages, the closest you'll get would be to use the send dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/514/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

I'd suggest playing around with the different `display` parameter settings to see if one of them might work

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

- page
- popup
- iframe
- touch
- wap

Comment: I have tried with different display parameter but it is not working